# "Simple" jquery validation example. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

right to the point. Have this form:

```
<form action="/Home/AskQuestion" method="post" id="question">
<div class="name">
<label>Name</label><br>
<input type="text" class="name required">
</div>
<div class="email">
<label>Email</label><br>
<input type="text" class="email required">
</div>
<div class="subject clearleft"><label>Subject</label><br> <select name="GroupId" class="emailSubject required" id="SubmitAQuestionEmailSubject"><option value="0">Customer Service</option><option value="1">Parts Request</option><option value="2">Product Question</option><option value="3">GCRR</option></select></div>
<div class="question clearleft">
<label>Question</label><br>
<textarea cols="20" rows="2" class="required"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

and this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("form").validate(); });
```

A google search for "jquery.validate example" gives me back all sorts of hits for a "working" sample just like this, which will prevent a form submission if any of the class="required" fields are blank. The example on the jquery validate page works for me.

My form submits anyway when I leave a "required" input blank. What the hell am I doing wrong?

Edit: Lost some info that was originally in this post somehow...

I am including both the jquery (1.6.1) and jquery validation (1.6 from the file header) script files. Jquery is included before jquery.validation. I've verified with firebug that the scripts are being found, and I'm not able to see any errors either in firebug or in the Firefox error console.

Edit2:

Interestingly, replacing the $("form").validate() with this code seems to trigger validation, but again, only the first input in the form (name) is validated...

```
$(".submit").click(function (evt) {
    if ($("form#question").validate().form()) {
        alert("valid");
    }
});
```

Comment: inputs on the form are missing "name" attributes, which are apparently required for validation to work. I added those and validation works as expected. I knew it was something simple I was missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you loading both jQuery and the validate plugin script?

In case you want to be lazy:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Each `input` value needs a `name=""` associated with it. The validation won't work otherwise.

Comment: Are you including your main js script that has the `$("form").validate();` function in it?

Comment: Yes, I've verified that code is there in the page. Again, looking at firebug.

Comment: Ah. totally missed that. In my defense, someone else created the form ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

#### Update 1

Since you said that you have included the jQuery validation plugin. Then, the only thing I can suggest, to you, is to try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#question").validate(); });
```

#### Update 2

You should add a `minlength` and a `maxlength` attribute to your inputs. Validation doesn't work like magic. It should get the properties to validate against from somewhere. So add a `minlength="2"` for your `Name` input element, for example.

Comment: Yeah, it's included, after the main jquery file. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @user803297: Updated my answer, try that and let me know if it worked.

Comment: The plugin is supposed to validate on if there is input in the field or not. Unless you add other rules.

Comment: understand what you're getting at, but the "required" class is supposed to have built-in support for simple text inputs.

Comment: @user803297: Yes, you are right, it has built in support to check if an input has anything typed in at all, but you also have missed the `name` attributes as someone else suggested. This creates a double trouble for you, client & server side.

Answer (score 0):

The method `validate()` is not built into JavaScript or jQuery. You need to define that method, or include the validation plugin Shef has mentioned.

EDIT:

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pdt6h/

Comment: Looks like my version of the plug in is a little out of date (1.6 versus 1.8), I'll try updating it and see what happens.

Comment: Played with your sample a bit, and noticed it's only validating the Name field? Also updating the plug in did not help me locally. Still scratching my head.